# T-SQL: BULK INSERT does not yield useful ERRORFILE

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

We currently have a routine RUNS DAILY and imports dozens of flat text files into foxpro.  I am working to convert this to TSQL.  I am working with the `BULK INSERT` command.

I created an sql command and an XML file for each of the dozens of flat files - one for each format.

For each file, I invoke a translation such as this from the command line:

```
sqlcmd -d MYDB -i Import_FILEA.sql -o Output_FILEA.txt
```

It works well (when it works).  The problem is that the data comes from a source that does not verify the data before they send it.  I don't blame them; I know how these things can happen.  But now I'm in a spot.

My sql script looks like this:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;
GO
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
GO
DELETE FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[FILEA];
GO
BULK INSERT 
  [MyDB].[dbo].[FILEA]
  FROM 'C:\Documents and Settings\somewhere\FILEA.DAT'
  WITH
  (
  DATAFILETYPE ='CHAR',
  FORMATFILE='C:\Documents and Settings\somewhere\translate_FILEA.xml',
  ERRORFILE ='C:\Documents and Settings\somewhere\ERR_FILEA.TXT',
  LASTROW   = 400000
  )
GO
```

The `LASTROW` argument is just for debugging purposes. The problem is that when this thing fails, it utterly fails and does not tell me the row or the field that is causing the problem.  It does not create any error file - or if it does, it ditches it soon after.  (I can see the file getting created and then it disappears - darndest thing.)

I'm so irritated with the thing I'm tempted to write a perl script or maybe some compiled vba with regexp to check the very few fields that are not character fields.  It's a small thing, but it's extra - and I'm worried about the next guy maintaining it.  (I don't think that any of the other guys can program in perl or are familiar with the regexp in .net)  Besides, the MSDN documentation makes it seem like the `bulk insert` should report the problem row in that error file.

Any ideas?  Is this a known problem?  Is there some parameter I'm missing?  Is there another way around this? Or is an external data format checker the right way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not gotten the error files to be useful for me.  I have two solutions to the problem:

(A)  Create and run a perl script to parse and check data fields of each flat file before running the imports.

(B)  Read in everything as text fields, but have extra fields for the correct data type which are set via and UPDATE SET command after each BULK INSERT.

I'm going with option (A) right now, because it occurred to me first and because I can make an automatic email to the data producers.